# how to dispatch action on input fields in reactjs?

Tags: redux, react-redux

hello this is the first time I am using redux in react

```
const userState = {
  fName: "",
  lName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  phone: "",
};

const user = (state = userState, action) => {
  return state;
};

export default user;
```

my redux store is

```
import {createStore} from "redux"
import user from "./reducer/userReducer"
 
const store = createStore(user)

export default store
```

I need an answer that how is dispatch an action on the input field to update the user data in store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create actionCreator and proper reducer

e.g

```
//action
export function changeUser(payload) {
  return {
    type: "CHANGE_USER",
    payload
  };
}

//reducer
function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_USER":
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and then dispatch with payload in your onChange event of input field
e.g

```
<input  onChange={(e) => dispatch(changeUser({ fName: e.target.value }))} />
```

for more details have a look at this code sample
https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-forked-iyzwj?file=/Page.js:411-502